# localization from inside the application in iphone

Tags: iphone, localization, application-settings

how can we localized our application from the button in built in application not from iphone setting. please suggest me something i am stuck in it. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

You change the bundle before you call for the translation;

```
NSString *bundle_path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                     pathForResource:@"Localizable"
                     ofType:@"strings"
                     inDirectory:nil
                     forLocalization:@"se"];

NSBundle *localized_bundle = [[NSBundle alloc]
                initWithPath:[bundle_path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];

NSString* translated = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"KEY", nil, localized_bundle, nil);
```

Comment: we have our own database. The user wants that when he/she chooses language inside the application the whole application respond according to that language & also the data inside the database. without the use of setting button in iphone

Comment: Yes, and that you can accomplish with the above code. Localization dependable strings for the app should be stored in localizeable files. The content of the app could be loaded with the provided language from a datasource.

Comment: is it possible to add a translator in application

Comment: is their any plugin to do that. how about apple glot

Comment: can you please answer me in more detail how i can implement the above code given by you.

Comment: as i found we have to create plist for every language which we wish to localized in our application